# Search LDAP without exceptions

Tags: c#, ldap

I am writing a performance-sensitive piece of code that will query an LDAP directory where it may be common to not find the object requested (a user or group).

We are using System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapConnection.SendRequest() to submit the query.

If the group/user is not found, SendRequest() throws a DirectoryOperationException.  Since this is performance sensitive, I would really like to avoid exceptions because of the performance hit for handling them.

Is there an alternate way to query LDAP such that I can get a null/false/empty collection result instead of an exception?

(I didn't see anything obvious like TrySendRequest, but I am not very familiar with LDAP filter syntax, so I thought perhaps there is something I'm missing)

Comment: Did you try the [DirectorySearcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher(v=vs.110).aspx) class?

Comment: I dare say that the query itself will cost you more than handling the exception. If you really are out for the tiniest bit of efficiency and the ldap is not too big: why not cache the relevant information and compary in memory ?

Comment: @Marged Well, that's the problem -- it's potentially, a really large LDAP directory.  Like potentially over 300,000 users (and it's in a product that ships, not internal code, so I don't have control over the the size/topology/etc of the directory)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [DirectorySearcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

It's [FindAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.findall(v=vs.110).aspx) method returns an empty collection if it doesn't find any result.

And it's [FindOne](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.findone(v=vs.110).aspx) method returns null if it does not find a match.

I am not sure about performance though. You need to test to see if using `DirectorySearcher` enhances the performance.

Comment: I will look into this one.  It appears to be targeting Active Directory.  Do you know whether it works with all RFC compliant LDAP servers? (we have to support multiple back ends.

Comment: @JMarsch, I am not really sure. I have only used it against active directory. 
But the search filter that it takes is a LDAP filter.